# Cannot access primefaces modules from war

Tags: primefaces, wildfly-8, server-configuration

I have an ear (`Selene.ear`) which contains a war (`SeleneWar.war`).

When I put `primefaces-5.0.jar` inside the `Selene.war` assembly (in `WEB-INF/lib`) I have no issues using the functionality. Anyway, I am a fan of thin deployments and I have been tried to setup primefaces as a WildFly module.

1) In wildfly/modules, I did create the folder `org/primefaces/main`. There I put `primefaces-5.0.jar` and the following `module.xml`

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="org.primefaces">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="primefaces-5.0.jar"/>
  </resources>

  <dependencies>
    <module name="javaee.api"/>
    <module name="javax.faces.api"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

2) In `selene.ear`, in `META-INF`, I have added the following `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <ear-subdeployments-isolated>true</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
  <sub-deployment name="SeleneWar.war">
    <dependencies>
      <module name="org.primefaces"/>
    </dependencies>
    <local-last value="true" />
  </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

It seems that everything is ok (Wildfly starts with no errors; if I remove the module folder then it start complaining about the missing dependencies). Yet, if I remove the primefaces jar from the war assembly the primefaces tags are not being processed, so it looks like the classes are not available.

I am using WildFly 8.1 on Java 7 on Linux.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue in **WildFly 8.2.0.Final**, and the way to make it work was just add this in the **jboss-deployment-structure.xml**: ( add **slot** and **export** attributes )

```
<dependencies>          
    <module name="org.primefaces" slot="main" export="true"/>  
</dependencies>
```

Comment: The `slot` is only to select a version of the module when you have several. `export`, though, did really work (I am editing your answer with the complete xml. Welcome to SO.

Comment: My bad, it actually did not work that day (even with `slot` and `export`); the first test worked because I did remove the primefaces jar from the  build process but it still got to the war as a dependency of primefaces-extensions. Once I tried with an application without the library, it could not find it as a module. Thanks anyway, and still welcome to SO.

Comment: Actually I finally make it work in another way.  I installed a new JSF library as a module, following this link: https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/StepsToAddAnyNewJSFImplementationOrVersionToWildFly , and then added the primefaces library to the generated [module.xml] by the cli installation script